# Configuring Infinispan Settings Not Present in Keycloak Wildfly's jboss-as-infinispan_4_0.xsd Schema

Tags: jboss, wildfly, keycloak, infinispan

I'm looking to configure some settings present in the version of Infinispan shipped with Keycloak's Wildfly from the following Infinispan provided xsd:

infinispan-config-8.2.xsd

The settings I'm looking for ('global-state' element) aren't present in the jboss-as-infinispan_4_0.xsd schema, though.

How do I leverage configuration features the version shipped with Wildfly supports?

I apologize if this is obvious (I'm new to Wildfly). I've spent a fair amount of time researching and am starting to think it cannot be done without write a custom submodule. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: The Infinispan version shipped with WildFly is set up for internal use really. If there's something missing there, you should really deploy Infinispan along with your application...etc. Btw, the latest Infinispan version is 9.4.x, so we'd suggest you use that instead of 8.2.x.

Comment: @GalderZamarreño I should have mentioned that Im using the standalone distribution of keycloak (a Redhat open source IdP). In the latest release they're using the newer infinispan version but I'm guessing they've not bundled the latest xsd with it. I'd agree, it seems like it would be easier if keycloak included its own infinispan version to use so we could have more control. I'd guess, though, that they might advise to run a separate infinispan data grid if I want advanced configuration options like that.

Comment: Yeah, you should definitely deploy your own Infinispan instances along your application, if you want to embed the datagrid in your app. Otherwise, you can create an Infinispan server cluster and talk to it remotely using our remote Java client. That will free up state from your application and with features such as near caching, you can get fast data speed while keeping your app lightweight.